# Visual Studio Extensibility: edit the undo list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

i'm trying to write a VS extension to solve [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817107/visual-studio-exclude-outlining-from-undo-redo-stack) and somehow exclude the outlining from undo/redo stack.

is there a way to intercept the insertion of a new undo item? i mean stop it before it is being added?

if not - can i get the list of undo items and edit it to remove those 'collapse' items?

Comment: This is not possible, the VS extension model doesn't expose the undo list internals.  Please avoid creating new questions about the same topic, just click the star on the reference question you linked.  If anything happens then you'll know about it.